# How to solve an underdetermined system under phase-only constraint?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm studying a problem related to the discrete Fourier transform.

I would like to solve an underdetermined system of K equations with N unknowns ($K<<N$). The system is as follows:

$F_k = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{-i(2\pi k n / N + \psi_n)}$ for $k \in \{k_1,...,k_K\} \in \mathbb{N}$

The unkowns are $\psi_n \in \mathbb{R}$ with $n \in \{1,...,N\}$, and $F_k \in \mathbb{C}$.

What is the most efficient way to solve such a system for a large number of variables (e.g. K=5000, N=500000)?